# Redirect shell output for ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, ffmpeg

I have simple ruby script :

```
 #! /usr/bin/env ruby
 require 'fileutils'

 FileUtils.rm "output.mkv" if File.exists?("outp    ut.mkv")
 pid = Process.spawn("ffmpeg -i wrong_file.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -qp 0 output.mkv", STDOUT => "output.txt", STDERR => "error.txt")

 puts "pid : #{pid}"
 Process.wait(pid)
```

**But, STDOUT and STDERR outputs into error.txt, why ?**

It looks, that ffmpeg have another exit codes ?(in usual case 0 for stdout, and 1 for stdin)

*Note: I don't want to use native shell redirect like '> output.txt 2> error.txt' because i want to get pid of ffmpeg process, not shell process and kill it in future.*

Comment: which version of ruby are you using?

Comment: ruby 2.0.0p598 (2014-11-13 revision 48408) [x86_64-darwin14.1.0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved - FFMPEG redirects all output to STDERR

Answer (score 0):

According to [spawn method documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Process.html#method-c-spawn) you should be doing this:

```
pid = Process.spawn("ffmpeg -i wrong_file.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -qp 0 output.mkv", :out => "output.txt", :err => "error.txt")
```

Comment: STDOUT, STDERR and :err, :out are aliases in spawn options. I tried with :err, :out  and it works, as described in issue above.